# rails link_to creates unwanted confirmation message in firefox and does not work in safari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, link-to, link-to-remote

I have the following link:

```
<%= link_to "", skill_path(skill), :class => "button-delete", :method => :delete,
 :remote => true %>
```

When the link is clicked on, the following confirmation popup appears:

```
This web page is being redirected to a new location. Would you like to resend 
 the form data you have typed to the new location?
```

The problem is I never created this confirmation.  If I remove ":remote => true", the confirmation goes away.  But I need the ":remote => true" because of the way I need the site to work.  Also, if I click "ok" to the confirmation message, the message reappears again but does not take me to the actual page.  In safari, the confirmation does not show but the new page still does not load.     Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you running this on firefox? https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/850324

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I have updated the question.  The link also does not work in safari.  I need to fix the code, not my browser.

Comment: You need to make your action respond to AJAX requests with something other than a redirect.

Comment: Ah, @meager ,  that worked!  Why is that?